# Javascript Looping through objects

Tags: javascript

```
var a = {
    element:'input',
    parent:'div1',
    name:'inp',
    type:'text',
    value:'aa'
}
```

I want to loop through this object starting from name attribute using for in loop
But I am unable to do this using for in loop
is there any way to loop through the object starting from the name attribute

Comment: Last value in an object shouldn't have a comma in it

Comment: What's stopping you from using for in loop?

Comment: starting with the name is not a regular sequence, it's possible to filter key values alphabetic,but this doesn't satisfy your need. I think you have to  handle the sequence in view. Actually, usually the view takes care of sequences in presenting the data but it will be more helpful if I know how you gonna represent this data? Also try use editor to wrap object in a code template

Comment: What are you going to do in your loop, and why does name need to come first?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var prop in a) {
  console.log(a[prop]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Old way:

```
for (var key in a) {
    if (a.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // todo something with a[key]
    }
}
```

ES6 way:

```
Object.keys(a).forEach(function(key) {
    // todo something with a[key]
});
```

Comment: Do these ways affect the sequence in which you get values? I don't think so.

Comment: "A for...in loop iterates over the properties of an object in an arbitrary order". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: ES6 way allows you to sort order of keys before go through loop

Comment: It's possible if you use sort function, but not the simple way you've wrote. Also the statement says arbitrary to enlighten that no special sort is applied by default. and furthermore, have a look at "Cross browser notes" section of http://mzl.la/1GIMLHi. it says any default order returned by For-in loop is non reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var keys = Object.keys(a);
var length = keys.length;
var startAt = keys.indexOf("name");
for(var i = 0; i < length ; i++) {
    var prop = keys[(i+startAt)%length];
    console.log(prop, a[prop]);
}
```

Or:

```
var keys = Object.keys(a).sort(function(a,b){ return a !== "name" });
for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var prop = keys[i];
    console.log(prop, a[prop]);
}
```

Or:

```
var keys = Object.keys(a);
var idx = keys.indexOf("name");
if(idx > 0) {
    var tmp = keys[0];
    keys[0] = keys[idx];
    keys[idx] = tmp;
}
for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var prop = keys[i];
    console.log(prop, a[prop]);
}
```

But keep in mind that objects are unordered lists even though most browsers keep object properties in the order in which they were added.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do it as follows:

```
function loopFromIndex(input, index) {
    var started = false;
    for (var property in input) {
        started = started || (index === property);
        if (started) {
            //process iteration
        }
    }
}
```

You are still looping the whole property set, but when you encounter the given `index`, you will start the real loop.